# Retrieve row index using growing

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a table.
I want retrieve the row number (better: I would like retrieve the row number that the table row bind)

**If I don't use growing** in the table I can retrieve the row number when I click on the `input` control in a row:

```js
    this.inputId = oEvent.getSource().getId(); // is "fasciaColore-__table0-5
    if (this.inputId.indexOf('-') > -1) {

        var aPart = this.inputId.split("-");
        this.inputId = aPart[0]
       
        this.rowIndex = aPart[2];
    }
```

**Using growing** the id is `fasciaColore-__clone22` , not  `fasciaColore-__table0-5`

How can I retrieve the id when I use growing in tables?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? _(Generally, getting the row index should not be necessary (the binding context is generally a way better approach, since row index can change due to sorting/filtering/etc). Getting the id of the row control should *never* need to happen, IMHO...)_

Comment: Then why not use the binding context? It will give you the object data for the current row, which you can manipulate as you want, and then write the modified object back to the binding context's path

Answer (score 0):

While I strongly agree with @Qualiture that you should use the Binding Context if possible, if you really want to get the index you could use `indexOfItem()` of the List:

```
oEvent.getSource().getParent().indexOfItem(oEvent.getSource())
```